# is it possible to generate Device Token within Phonegap to use user defined push notifications?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

As the title says, i want to develop web application and compile it to native iOS using Phonegap. Application should send specific push notifications to specific users.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a third party service with a remote API.

PushWoosh already has a great PhoneGap plugin designed specifically for easy integration of push notifications. Urban Airship are still working on smth similar.

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/

Another small, but important thing: Remote API is a Premium account feature in PushWoosh, however, you will pay at most 200 EUR per year for their Premium, while pricing at UA is simply unreasonable.

Comment: Well from document you linked seems like i can do this via Java Script on PushWoosh. Agree about UA pricing which is lower than AppMobi ie.

Comment: Yes, the idea of the Pushwoosh plugin for Phonegap is to provide Javascript interface for push notification. Pushwoosh seamless integration takes the heavy load and makes sure you don't have to write native code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of push notification you mean?

Local notifications can be set (on delay) through a plugin like this one:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/LocalNotifications

If you mean push notifications from a remote server: The phonegap wiki might help you: 
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41670190/Push%20Notifications%20on%20IOS

It uses a external service called airship.